# How do I click on the Hyper link text Automatically when window active using auto hot key scripting / Batch File

Tags: batch-file, autohotkey

I am new to auto hot key scripting can any one help me out how do I click on the hyper link text using Auto hot key script / Batch File.

My requirement is :

Right click on the Desktop --> In Screen Resolution Screen --> Advanced Settings. So I want to click on the Advanced Settings link automatically when I run the auto hot key script . Please do find the below Image:

[image: Display Settings]

Please Find My Below Code Using Mouse Cursor .. I Had Achieved through Mouse cursor but I don't think so that this is going to be the final solution.

```
#SingleInstance force
#persistent

Run,Desk.cpl
SetTimer, Check, 100
return

Check:

IfWinActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass
MouseMove, 658, 368
Click  
Sleep, 1000

IfWinActive, ahk_class #32770
MouseMove, 212, 64
Click  
Sleep, 1000

IfWinActive, ahk_class #32770
MouseMove, 93, 360
Click  
Sleep, 1000

IfWinActive, ahk_class #32770
MouseMove, 81, 392
Click  
Sleep, 1000

IfWinActive, ahk_class #32770
ControlClick,&Apply,ahk_class #32770

IfWinActive, ahk_class #32770
ControlClick,OK,ahk_class #32770

IfWinActive, ahk_class #32770
ControlClick,&Yes,ahk_class #32770

IfWinActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass
ControlClick,OK,ahk_class CabinetWClass

IfWinNotExist, ahk_class CabinetWClass {

ExitApp

return

}
```

Comment: too many possibilities...

Comment: My Requirement was Right Click On the Desktop --> Click On Advanced Settings ---> Click On Monitor Tab ---> Change the True Color to 32 Bit So this should be done automatically when i run the script

Comment: Check the AutoHotKey help docs and try it by yourself first. If you fail, come here with the failure code and we would be able to help you.

Comment: maybe [this can be helpful](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17604/change-desktop-resolution-with-a-keyboard-shortcut/) <-- Click

Comment: Did you even attempt to read that?! Except the fact that I am almost 100% sure you asked twice already.... The program he linked to provides the option to change the color depth as well! At least give people that help you a chance... As well the words requirement and urgent are a magnet for downvotes here!

Comment: Yes i had read that , And i even tried the link which is provided by freestock.tk , In that scenario we need to mandatory install the Hot key resolution changer without installting the application i want to run it through all the 32 bit systems with an exe file.

Answer (score 1):

This AutoHotkey script invokes the hyperlink directly by using Microsoft Active Accessibility (MSAA).

This script opens the windows as required and sets True Color (32 bit) (tested on Windows 7) by using direct methods rather than by sending clicks to coordinates.

Note: the script requires Acc.ahk.
Acc library (MSAA) and AccViewer download links - AutoHotkey Community
https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=26201

Note: in my case the window title for the popup window was '(Multiple Monitors) and Intel(R) HD Graphics Family Properties',
you may need to change this in the script if your window has a different title.

```
q:: ;set True Color (32 bit) (tested on Windows 7)
windir := A_WinDir
vTarget = %windir%\system32\control.exe desk.cpl,Settings,@Settings
Run, %vTarget%
WinWaitActive, Screen Resolution ahk_class CabinetWClass

ControlGet, hCtl, Hwnd, , DirectUIHWND4, Screen Resolution ahk_class CabinetWClass
oAcc := Acc_Get("Object", "4.1.1.14", 0, "ahk_id " hCtl)
if (oAcc.accName(0) = "Advanced settings")
oAcc.accDoDefaultAction(0)

vWinCriteria = (Multiple Monitors) and Intel(R) HD Graphics Family Properties ahk_class #32770
WinWaitActive, %vWinCriteria%
WinGet, hWnd, ID, %vWinCriteria%
SendMessage, 0x1330, 1, , SysTabControl321, ahk_id %hWnd% ;TCM_SETCURFOCUS := 0x1330
Control, ChooseString, True Color (32 bit), ComboBox2, ahk_id %hWnd%

ControlGetText, vText, Button5, ahk_id %hWnd%
if (vText = "OK")
ControlClick, Button5, ahk_id %hWnd%

MsgBox % "done"
Return
```

Useful links:
Executing Control Panel Items (Windows)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144191(v=vs.85).aspx

Canonical Names of Control Panel Items (Windows)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330741(v=vs.85).aspx

[found by searching for: AutoHotkey "True Color (32 bit)"]
Dual Display Toggle (Display Properties Replacement) - Scripts and Functions - AutoHotkey Community
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/22372-dual-display-toggle-display-properties-replacement/

[EDIT:]
[found by searching for: AutoHotkey DEVMODE]
[SOLVED] How To Change Resolution of Both Monitors At Once? - AutoHotkey Community
https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=19467

The link has a custom function, ChangeDisplaySettings,
which may do what you want, (but I would urge you
to check the code thoroughly before executing it):

```
ChangeDisplaySettings(False, 32)
```

Note: it may only work correctly with the 32-bit version of AutoHotkey
(which can be run on 64-bit Windows).

[EDIT 2:]
I wrote some code to query rather than set the value:

```
w:: ;get display data
vSizeTCHAR := A_IsUnicode ? 64 : 32
vSizeDEVMODE := 92 + (vSizeTCHAR * 2)
vOffsetBitsPerPel := 40 + (vSizeTCHAR * 2) ;dmBitsPerPel

;ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS := -1 
;ENUM_REGISTRY_SETTINGS := -2
VarSetCapacity(DEVMODE, vSizeDEVMODE, 0)
vRet := DllCall("EnumDisplaySettings", Ptr,0, UInt,-1, Ptr,&DEVMODE)

MsgBox % NumGet(DEVMODE, vOffsetBitsPerPel, "UInt")
Return
```

Best of luck!